# Missing required key 'Message- AWS SNS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to send SMS from a aws sns function were we provide the mobile number and text message and use SNS to deliver that message but I had an error

> {"Error":{"message":"Missing required key 'Message' in
> params","code":"MissingRequiredParameter","time":"2022-04-11T16:14:53.306Z"}}

Can any one suggest a solution?

```
  router.post('/send-text', (req, res) => {
    
       var dynamoDBConfiguration = { 
         "accessKeyId": "X...",
         "secretAccessKey": "l...",
         "region": "eu-west-3" };
         
        AWS.config.update(dynamoDBConfiguration);
     
    
      console.log("Message = " + req.body.message);
      console.log("Number = " + req.body.number);
      console.log("Subject = " + req.body.subject);
      var params = {
        Message: req.query.message,
        PhoneNumber: '+' + req.query.number,
        MessageAttributes: {
          'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': req.query.subject
          }
        }
      };
    
      var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31' }).publish(params).promise();
    
      publishTextPromise.then(
        function (data) {
          res.end(JSON.stringify({ MessageID: data.MessageId }));
        }).catch(
          function (err) {
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ Error: err }));
          });
```

Comment: Carefully compare the values that you're logging to the ones that you're providing in the API call. They're not the same.